# Codeigniter rewriting, how to skip index.php?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Currently I am trying to learn CodeIgniter.

This works:

```
 http://localhost/NewsPage/index.php/news/fenerana
```

But I want to make it work when it is:

```
http://localhost/NewsPage/news/fenerana
```

How can I do this?
My current routes.php file is:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My suggestion, though, is to use this version:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. My .htaccess file currently is: RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Deny from all
However, it is not working?

Comment: @JWCMay This answer is also 7 years old. The recipe is still the same according to the documentation, but you'd might be using Nginx instead of Apache now.

Answer (score 2):

First go to application/config/config.php and turn 'index_page' to empty:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then use .htaccess(put it in the same level with CI index.php), like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images_folder|css_folder_maybe)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of the directory name. More info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html